# Proof of Logarithm map formulae from $SO(3)$ to $\mathfrak {so}(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

According to [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)), there also exist a logarithm map
$$\log:SO(3) \to \mathfrak {so}(3).$$
Suppose a vector $t \in\mathfrak {so}(3)$ and $t=\|t\|w$, according to exponential map
$$R = \cos\|t\|I+(1-\cos \|t\|)ww^T+\sin \|t\|w^{\land}.$$
So the inverse(i.e. from rotation matrix $R$ to vector $t$) is
$$\|t\|=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(R)-1}{2}\right)\tag 1$$
$$w = \frac{1}{2\sin(\|t\|)}
\begin{bmatrix} r_{32}-r_{23} \\ r_{13}-r_{31} \\ r_{21}-r_{12}
\end{bmatrix} \tag 2$$
where $r_{ij}$ is elements of $R$. I can easily derive (1) while stuck in (2), can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard formula accompanying the [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), obvious if only you use the right notation!  The important thing is is to streamline your orthogonal matrix *R*. Its logarithm is the antisymmetric matrix *K*, defined by the linear cross product at the end of your expansion of *R*,
$$
K\equiv  
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -t_3 & t_2 \\
t_3 & 0 & -t_1 \\
-t_2 & t_1 & 0
\end{array}\right] ~,
$$
so that $\| t\|^2= -\frac{\operatorname {Tr} (K^2)}{2}\equiv \| K\|^2$; hence  $K=\|t\| \hat K$   with  $\| \hat K\|=1$  .

Now the crucial thing is to re-express the Rodrigues formula in this notation,
$$
R=(R^T)^{-1}= e^K= {\mathbb 1} +   \sin \|t\| ~ \hat K + (1-\cos\|t\|) \hat K ^2 . 
$$
Note how *different* the coefficient of the identity looks, contrasted to your vector expression: it is not a mistake (read up on the point in WP....  well-wishers frequently "correct" it! Of course, this expression follows directly from the characteristic equation for *K*, not Rodrigues' original argument).

So, tracing this expression, and the fact that *K* is traceless since antisymmetric, your (1) follows.

Now antisymmetrize *R*,
$$
\frac{R-R^T}{2}= \sin\|t\| ~ \hat K ,
$$
since the other two terms are symmetric matrices. Convert your "unit" antisymmetric matrix to your unit vector *w* and you have (2).